# unable to send apache logs to Datadog agent

Tags: docker, datadog

I am trying Datadog agent to visualize apache logs. **Apache is running inside a docker container, And Datadog-agent is also running as a docker container on same host**.
**Note**: I am able to find all container logs, but **unable** to get logs from apache's access.log file.
Used following command to start Datadog-agent.

```
docker run -d --name datadog-agent \
       -e DD_API_KEY=$DD_API_KEY \
       -e DD_LOGS_ENABLED=true \
     -e DD_LOGS_CONFIG_EXPECTED_TAGS_DURATION=10m \
       -e DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL=true \
       -e DD_CONTAINER_EXCLUDE_LOGS="name:datadog-agent" \
       -e DD_LOGS_CONFIG_DOCKER_CONTAINER_FORCE_USE_FILE=true \
       -v /proc/:/host/proc/:ro \
       -v /opt/datadog-agent/run:/opt/datadog-agent/run:rw \
       -v /sys/fs/cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
       datadog/agent:latest
```

This is how I used conf.yaml file in datadog-agent container.
Filepath: conf.d/apache.d/conf.yaml

```
logs:

# - type : (mandatory) type of log input source (tcp / udp / file)
#   port / path : (mandatory) Set port if type is tcp or udp. Set path if type is file
#   service : (mandatory) name of the service owning the log
#   source : (mandatory) attribute that defines which integration is sending the logs
#   sourcecategory : (optional) Multiple value attribute. Can be used to refine the source attribute
#   tags: (optional) add tags to each logs collected

- type: file
  path: "/var/log/apache2/access.log"
  service: "apache"
  source: "apache"
  sourcecategory:
```

Yet I don't see any logs in datadog-agent dashboard.
I check the track trace from datadog agent I got this

```
Logs Agent
==========
    Reliable: Sending compressed logs in HTTPS to agent-http-intake.logs.datadoghq.com on port 443
    BytesSent: 63387
    EncodedBytesSent: 11210
    LogsProcessed: 148
    LogsSent: 148

  apache
  ------
    - Type: file
      Path: /var/log/apache2/access.log
      Status: Error: cannot read file /var/log/apache2/access.log: stat /var/log/apache2/access.log: no such file or directory
      BytesRead: 0
      Average Latency (ms): 0
      24h Average Latency (ms): 0
      Peak Latency (ms): 0
      24h Peak Latency (ms): 0
```

name of my apache container is **apache**.
Can anyone suggest me how can I read a access.log file from my apache container using Datadog-agent?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but you should not be posting API keys publicly.

I recommend you edit your message to delete the key, and then go rotate that key in Datadog. Right now anyone that sees your message will have programmatic access to send data into your account

https://docs.datadoghq.com/account_management/api-app-keys/#what-to-do-if-an-api-or-application-key-was-exposed

Comment: Thanks @Eric Allen for your suggestion, I Highly appreciate your action.

Comment: You have the agent running in one container, and apache in another. You're configuring the agent to read `/var/log/apache2/access.log` but that path exists in the apache container not in the agent container so the agent is throwing an error when trying to read it. You either need to have the access.log in a shared volume between the two containers or have them exposed through docker logs

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the user 'dd-agent' does not have permission to access the log directory.

You can set specific permission using POSIX Access Control Lists (ACLs). Install 'acl' using your favorite package manager.
For example in Ubuntu: `apt-get install acl`
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs

Give the user 'dd-agent' read and execute permission to '/var/log/apache':

```
setfacl -m u:dd-agent:rx /var/log/apache
```

As the logs are rotated you'll also want to set these permissions on all the newly create log files. Create a new logrotate config file:

```
sudo touch /etc/logrotate.d/dd-agent_ACLs
```

Edit that config file to add some ACL commands to run postrotate (for example):

```
/var/log/apache/*.log {
 postrotate
 /usr/bin/setfacl -m g:dd-agent:rx /var/log/apache/access.log
 /usr/bin/setfacl -m g:dd-agent:rx /var/log/apache/error.log
 endscript
}
```

https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/guide/setting-file-permissions-for-rotating-logs/